# XtraReport - Visualizar report mas não deixar imprimir

Tags: c#, relatório, xtrareport

Estou utilizando o construtor de relatórios `XtraReport`, e utilizando `ReportPrintTool` para visualizar e depois imprimir.

Porém, estava precisando, apenas visualizar, bloqueando a impressão. Seria possível?

Botão visualizar:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // botao imprimir
    {
        // Create a report. 
        imp_orcamento report = new imp_orcamento(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));

        // Show the report's preview. 
        ReportPrintTool tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);
        tool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // botao imprimir
    {
        // Create a report. 
        imp_orcamento report = new imp_orcamento(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));

        // Show the report's preview. 
        ReportPrintTool tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);

        tool.Report.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.File, false);
        tool.Report.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.ExportFile, false);
        tool.Report.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.Print, false);
        tool.Report.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.Save, false);
        tool.Report.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.Open, false);
        tool.Report.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.SendFile, false);
        tool.Report.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.PageSetup, false);
        tool.Report.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.PrintDirect, false);


        tool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
    }
```